# Libcurl error when using luaJIT (Windows)

Tags: lua

I was making a discord bot with luaJIT using the [discord.lua](https://github.com/videah/discord.lua) module i installed the libcurl binaries from the [curl website](https://curl.haxx.se/download.html) i put the executables in my folder where my source lua file is. But the discord.lua module wasn't working because of luajit-curl.lua on line 28 where the ffi.load is. I don't know what is wrong and I can't figure out how to fix this issue.

Error in console:

```
luajit64\luajit.exe: .\discord\luajit-request\luajit-curl.lua:28: cannot load module 'libcurl': %1 is not a valid Win32 application.

stack traceback:
        [C]: in function 'load'
        .\discord\luajit-request\luajit-curl.lua:28: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\discord\luajit-request\init.lua:30: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\discord\wrapper.lua:25: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\discord\client.lua:29: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        .\discord\init.lua:32: in main chunk
        [C]: in function 'require'
        bot.lua:2: in main chunk
        [C]: at 0x0140002980
```

Comment: Seems pretty clear, though FFI can be painful to sort out. But almost certainly the libcurl module that FFI is loading doesn't have Windows entry points. Are you sure it is finding the 32-bit shared library?

Comment: That error is often caused when a 32-bit application tries to load a 64-bit library, or vice versa. Make sure your architectures for the two match.